# How to add required attribute on specific table row index in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have module where if I ticked the checkbox the state isRequiredDate **false** will turn to true else will back to false. Based on my research they suggest to use ! state to change the boolean. However when I ticked the first row the required attribute applying to all table row even I clicked only the first row. I don't know what this called but I hope the details is good enough.

On my state:

```
isRequiredNewCheckDate:false,
```

Handler CheckBox:

```
handleChange = async (e, index) => {

    let newArray = "";
    
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
        
     

        await this.setState({
            isRequiredNewCheckDate: !this.state.isRequiredNewCheckDate
        })
        

    } else {


        await this.setState({
            isRequiredNewCheckDate: !this.state.isRequiredNewCheckDate
        })


    }

   

};
```

Input Checkbox:

```
<input
    ref={"ref_" + id}
    type="checkbox"
    id={"checkbox_" + id}
    name={"checkbox_" + id}
    value={id}
    data-newchekdate={new_check_date}
    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,id)}
    
    
/>
```

Here is the input date where I need to set the required attribute once the checkbox ticked:

```
<td className="boder-gray">
    <input type="date"  value={new_check_date == null ? "" : new_check_date} name="checkDate" required={this.state.isRequiredNewCheckDate} onChange={e => this.handleInputNewCheckDate(e, index, id,  check)} className="form-control" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `id` in the `input` is the index, and it is unique for each row. In this case, turn your `isRequiredNewCheckDate` boolean in an array, then display accordingly:

Handler checkbox:

```
handleChange = async (e, index) => {

    let newArray = [...this.state.isRequiredNewCheckDate];
    newArray[index] = e.target.checked;
    await this.setState({isRequiredNewCheckDate: newArray});
};
```

In HTML code:

```
<td className="boder-gray">
    <input type="date"  value={new_check_date == null ? "" : new_check_date} name="checkDate" required={this.state.isRequiredNewCheckDate[id]} onChange={e => this.handleInputNewCheckDate(e, index, id,  check)} className="form-control" />
</td>
```

It should work properly.